# How can I display octal notation of permissions with ls - and can octal represent all permissions?

Tags: ls, coreutils

After looking at the `man` page for `ls` on my system and searching Google, I see there **[IS a hack of way to use `awk` or `perl` to show octal permissions](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/140509-ls-show-numeric-permission-bit.html)** when using `ls`, but with `bash` is there anything more native?

#### Standard output of ls -alh

```
$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 user  group   170B May 20 20:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  17 user  group   578B May 20 20:03 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 user  group     0B May 20 20:03 example
-rw-r--r--   1 user  group     0B May 20 20:03 example-1
-rw-r--r--   1 user  group     0B May 20 20:03 example-3
```

#### Desired output including octal representation of permissions

```
$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1775  5 user  group   170B May 20 20:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 1775 17 user  group   578B May 20 20:03 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1644  1 user  group     0B May 20 20:03 example
-rw-r--r-- 1644  1 user  group     0B May 20 20:03 example-1
-rw-r--r-- 1644  1 user  group     0B May 20 20:03 example-3
```

(disclaimer: not sure if those octals are *exactly* right)

#### Reasoning

I am more familiar with the `drwxr-xr-x` notation for permissions but sometimes when the dashes fall in odd places I might mis-read it at a quick glance. I'd like to see the octal equivalent as well.

#### Conversion Ability (question part 2)

I think a long time ago octal permissions might have been limited to `000` - `777` but in recent times there are some things like `set-group-ID` and `sticky` that have given us octals with 4 places like `1775`. Is it possible to represent every possible permission in octal format? If it is not then I'd better understand why bash's `ls` command doesn't seem to have this format.

Comment: Those numerics (e.g.777) are not "decimals" (base 10 numbers), but rather octal (base 8).

Comment: ls cant but find can. $ find .  -printf "%f %m \n"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also use `stat` to get a `ls`-like output but I use a different approach to format the output: I use `TAB` as a delimiter (allows for easier parsing afterwards, if needed), format the time via `stat` and finally filter the output with [`numfmt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) (included in GNU [`coreutils` >= 8.21](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-02/msg00085.html) *2013-02-14*) to get nice file sizes:

```sh
stat --printf="%A\t%a\t%h\t%U\t%G\t%s\t%.19y\t%n\n" * | numfmt --to=iec-i --field=6 --delimiter='     ' --suffix=B
```

Note the delimiter used for `numfmt` is also a <kbd>Tab</kbd> (to input in terminal hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>).
This is what the output looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  755 2   don users   4.0KiB  2013-05-17 03:37:02 150905-adwaita-x-dark-light-1.3
drwxr-xr-x  755 8   don users   4.0KiB  2011-10-13 07:30:39 Adwaita Slim
drwxr-xr-x  755 3   don users   4.0KiB  2013-05-17 19:26:41 Away
drwxr-xr-x  755 5   don users   4.0KiB  2013-05-17 03:09:14 elementary
-rw-r--r--  644 1   don users   539KiB  2013-05-10 00:32:14 gdm.jpg
-rw-r--r--  644 1   don users   1.5MiB  2013-05-19 04:30:16 gnome-shell-3.8.2.tar.xz
drwxrwxr-x  775 4   don users   4.0KiB  2013-05-18 18:34:38 gnome-themes-standard-3.8.1
-rw-r--r--  644 1   don users   3.7MiB  2013-05-18 18:30:06 gnome-themes-standard-3.8.1.tar.xz
drwxrwxr-x  775 17  don users   4.0KiB  2013-05-18 18:37:05 gtk+-3.8.2
-rw-r--r--  644 1   don users   14MiB   2013-05-18 18:30:56 gtk+-3.8.2.tar.xz
drwxr-xr-x  755 13  don users   4.0KiB  2013-05-18 02:41:51 MediterraneanNight-2.02
-rw-r--r--  644 1   don users   603B    2013-05-19 20:07:26 python-pytaglib.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  644 1   don users   442KiB  2013-05-19 00:33:27 Stripes.jpg
```

***Note***: as per *cwd*'s comment, on `OSX`, `coreutils` commands are `gstat` and `gnumfmt`.

Comment: wow that certainly looks exactly like an `ls` listing. nice!

Comment: while this looks really good I want it to work with systems that aren't the most cutting edge as well, and `numfmt` seems to require a pretty new system as I just checked out corutils and 8.21 fairly new and as you mentioned it requires > 8.21 for numfmt. Also on OS X (which is not really linux I know) the stat command seems to be having trouble with the the `--printf` part.

Comment: @cwd: Under OS X, you have `-t timefmt`, and `-f` is equivalent to `--printf=`. At least if I read the [man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/stat.1.html) correctly. (No system to test on here).

Comment: @Sukminder - you're right about the changes but some of the other flags don't line up as well. I'm going to give up try and install GNU stat (if I can find it in a homebrew repo) because I want it to work the same as it does on the Linux boxes I work with. ( I've already got GNU sed so hopefully I can soon use the same syntax on both systems for stat too). Unfortunately right now coreutils is at 8.21 with homebrew though :(

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks! mb update your answer to use the >= instead of just >  - also, for others - on OS X the commands from coreutils are gnumfmt and gstat. how odd. thanks! now i have it working on linux and osx!

Comment: This doesn't work on my system. I see `numfmt`, I can't even find that tool in any package for Fedora. I have coreutils 8.5, there isn't any numfmt in that package.

Comment: Yeah I finally found it. My ancient coreutils doesn't include it @ 8.5.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `numfmt` again? I ignore this part `numfmt --to=iec-i --field=6 --delimiter='     ' --suffix=B`  and the output is the same

Comment: @MaXi32 the `numfmt ...` converts the file size - resp. the 6th field separated by a TAB - to a human readable number. **||** note: you have to replace whatever is between the `'` of the `--delimiter=` with an actual TAB **manually**! if it is just a space or empty, nothing will be converted. - unfortunately most terminals do not paste an actual TAB and also something like `\t` or `%t` does not work as only one character is allowed.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `stat` command and get roughly what you want:

```
$ stat -c '%A %a %h %U %G %s %y %n' *
drwxrwxr-x 775 2 saml saml 4096 2013-05-16 22:02:13.230463837 -0400 alsa
drwxrwxr-x 775 31 saml saml 4096 2013-03-26 12:09:20.707827127 -0400 apps
-rw-rw-r-- 664 1 saml saml 43627 2013-05-18 12:28:32.157583577 -0400 autosave.h2song
-rw-rw-r-- 664 1 saml saml 3283 2013-05-18 02:49:41.565154101 -0400 bbbb
drwxrwxr-x 775 4 saml saml 4096 2013-05-03 06:56:50.087842384 -0400 bin
-rw-rw-r-- 664 1 saml saml 4403 2013-05-18 19:20:05.819681196 -0400 blahblah
```

Here's the cleaned up version if you want it:

```
$ stat -c '%A %a %h %U %G %s %y %n' *| sed 's/\.[[:digit:]]\+[ ]\+-[[:digit:]]\+/ /'
drwxrwxr-x 775 2 saml saml 4096 2013-05-16 22:02:13  alsa
drwxrwxr-x 775 31 saml saml 4096 2013-03-26 12:09:20  apps
-rw-rw-r-- 664 1 saml saml 43627 2013-05-18 12:28:32  autosave.h2song
-rw-rw-r-- 664 1 saml saml 3283 2013-05-18 02:49:41  bbbb
drwxrwxr-x 775 4 saml saml 4096 2013-05-03 06:56:50  bin
-rw-rw-r-- 664 1 saml saml 4403 2013-05-18 19:20:05  blahblah
```

Take a look at the `stat` man page for more format operators that you can use in addtion to the ones above.

#### References

- [stat man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)

Comment: That looks pretty good - even works with the sticky bit! thanks! wish the file sizes lined up better but its close enough :)

Comment: @cwd the file sizes will align just fine if you remove the `%h` which is what changes the line length. `%h` is the number of hard links to the file which is not something you need most times you run ls.

Comment: Did you mean `%s` for size, not `%B`?

Comment: @Sukminder, that's what I would've used but I thought he had the size being displayed in bytes in the original question? Isn't that what the 170B is?

Comment: B, K, M, G would be fine - just human readable is preferable

Comment: Yes, he uses `-h` for ls which gives human. But `%B` in stat gives block size, `%b` gives number of `%B` sized block used, and `%s` total size in bytes. So bytes would be `%B * %b`

Comment: @Sukminder, my bad, I misread the %b to mean bytes. Thanks for the catch. I'll fix the answer to include %s.

Answer (score 1):

This awk code transforms the rights from symbol to digit. But it covers only the normal cases (i.e. at least not `sStT`):

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[-dsbclp]([-r][-w][-x]){3}[.+]?$/ 
  {for(i=0;i<3;i++) {symbol=substr($1,2+i*3,3); sum=0; 
    if (substr(symbol,1,1) == "r") sum+=4;
    if (substr(symbol,2,1) == "w") sum+=2;
    if (substr(symbol,3,1) == "x") sum+=1;
    printf "%d",sum;}}'
```

And this produces the output you want:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[-dsbclp]([-r][-w][-x]){3}[.+]?$/ 
  {printf "%s ",$1; 
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {symbol=substr($1,2+i*3,3); sum=0; 
      if (substr(symbol,1,1) == "r") sum+=4;
      if (substr(symbol,2,1) == "w") sum+=2;
      if (substr(symbol,3,1) == "x") sum+=1;
      printf "%d",sum;}
    $1=""; print}'
```

Comment: per the question - `I see there IS a hack of way to use awk or perl to show octal permissions when using ls, but with bash is there anything more native` - just sayin

Comment: @cwd bash can do everything I used with awk.