# Format stat to look like ls -l

Tags: bash

I'd list as much as possible to replicate `ls -l` with `stat` so that I can see the octal numbers instead.

I have got quite close with `stat -c '%a------- %h %U %G %5s %.16y %n' *`

```
me@PC:/etc/apt$ ls -l
total 76
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  2 15:50 apt.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr  9  2020 auth.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 28 03:26 keyrings
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 12  2021 preferences.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2796 Aug 23 11:02 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  2 15:50 sources.list.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  3071 Aug 23 11:02 sources.list.distUpgrade
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  3071 Jun 27 13:04 sources.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18951 Mar 27 17:15 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17320 Feb  7  2022 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  2 15:50 trusted.gpg.d

me@PC:/etc/apt$ stat -c '%a------- %h %U %G %5s %.16y %n' *
755------- 2 root root  4096 2022-09-02 15:50 apt.conf.d
755------- 2 root root  4096 2020-04-09 06:21 auth.conf.d
755------- 2 root root  4096 2022-07-28 03:26 keyrings
755------- 2 root root  4096 2021-07-12 06:26 preferences.d
664------- 1 root root  2796 2022-08-23 11:02 sources.list
755------- 2 root root  4096 2022-09-02 15:50 sources.list.d
664------- 1 root root  3071 2022-08-23 11:02 sources.list.distUpgrade
664------- 1 root root  3071 2022-06-27 13:04 sources.list.save
644------- 1 root root 18951 2022-03-27 17:15 trusted.gpg
644------- 1 root root 17320 2022-02-07 22:44 trusted.gpg~
755------- 2 root root  4096 2022-09-02 15:50 trusted.gpg.d
```

All the data is there but the date format is slightly off.

Can it be piped through xargs and printf or something to reformat the date or is the closest I can get?

Comment: Since you mention piping through `printf`, have you tried output formatting via the `--printf` option?

Comment: the date format in LS is actually mixed, as it only shows either year or time of day, depending on the age of the file.   any such script  would have to switch formats to mimic LS's behavior

Comment: I like the idea very much, but let me correct your state: All the data is there AND the date format is MUCH BETTER! :) (I use `ls` always with long-iso timeformat) Good job btw, after octal code why do you add 6 dashes?

Comment: That seems to be the GNU implementation of `stat` you're using. Note that there are many different implementations of a `stat` command completely incompatible between each other.

Comment: The `ls` timestamp format also varies with the locale and system, and also whether the file was last modified in the last 6 months or earlier or in the future.

Comment: With GNU `stat` you want `%A` for the type and permissions in symbolic form.

Comment: And `ls` mishandles funny characters in filenames. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @gabor.zed I add the extra dashes so that the columns line up with the ls output and the ls output has dashes in it so it looks a bit similar

Comment: Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76521/how-can-i-display-octal-notation-of-permissions-with-ls-and-can-octal-represen

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little script, to start with:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(stat --printf="%a\t%h\t%U\t%G\t%s\t%Y\t%n\n" *); do
  IFS=$'\t' read -r -a FP <<<$i; 
  echo ${FP[0]} ${FP[1]} ${FP[2]} ${FP[3]} ${FP[4]} $(date -d@${FP[5]} "+%Y.%m.%d. %H:%M") ${FP[6]} 
done
```

This way you can handle every file property. For example if the username or group is too long, ls shows the uid/gid instead, and so on.

Comment: Not quite the answer to the question, but a helpful place to start so have an upvote!